# Как с через win32api узнать какая программа активна из Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, процесс

Получаю список процессов через `EnumProcesses`, далее получаю нужную информацию о файле процесса из `OpenProcess` и `GetModuleFileNameEx`. Можно ли получить еще информацию о том, от какого процесса в определенный момент активно окно?

Comment: [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) + [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid). Windows сейчас под рукой нет, рабочий код дать не могу.

Comment: @insolor Да используя данные функции получил поток активного окна, но нужно дальше получить какому процессу принадлежит поток...

Comment: Все разобрался, я pid спутал с hpid